# Edit table to allow all fields show as text boxes to modify

Tags: jquery

Hi i have table have two buttons edit and delete
i need by jquery make edit to this tables meaning show textboxes inside table to edit 
the ID,Name,Country
my code as following

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(function () {
            $("#btn").click(function ()
            {
                var x = $("#txt1").val();
                var y = $("#txt2").val();
                var z = $("#txt3").val();
                $("#tb").append("<tr> <td>" + x + "</td> <td>" + y + "</td> <td>" + z + "</td><td> <input type='button'class='c' value='Delete'/></td><td> <input type='button'value='Edit'/></td></tr>");


            });
            $("#tb").on("click", ".c", function () {
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        ID<input type="text" id="txt1" /><br />
        Name<input type="text" id="txt2" /><br />
        Country<input type="text" id="txt3" /><br />
        <input type="button" value="add" id="btn" />

        <table id="tb">
            <tr><td>ID</td><td>Name</td><td>Country</td><td><input type="button" class="c" value="Delete" /></td><td><input type="button"value="Edit" /></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What i need to make function to edit id,name,country and show as text boxes to edit it

Comment: Do you want the table items such as `<td>ID</td>` to be a textbox? Or do you want your textboxes before the table to be able to edit the table items?

Comment: There are numerous plugins for this